# .Htaccess rules to redirect respective HTTP links to HTTP and HTTPS to HTTPS?

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

First, here's the .htaccess rule I currently use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is great, and redirects every link of my old domain to the very respective link in new domain. That is, `http://olddomain.com/1.html` is redirected to `http://example.com/1.html` and so forth.

But it doesn't redirect `https://olddomain.com/1.html` to `https://example.com/1.html`

And just so you know I tried, below are the rules I also happened to test. Unfortunately they're creating some kind of loop, and the redirection doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, can someone give me the rules redirect http pages to http and https pages to https? Thanks.

Comment: any one, I really need this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#if https on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that returned a 500 internal server error. Redirection didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's because olddomain.com and example.com are on the same server and also share the same SSL cert?

Comment: Sorry. The spaces after the comma shouldn't be there. Don't know how they got there. I edited the post to correct it. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: It's not working completely. `http://olddomain.com` redirects just fine to `http://example.com`. But when I go to `HTTPS://olddomain.com`, it shows the same URL in the address bar, while showing content from `example.com` (and the content is broken. No styling.)

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache (or use another browser)? Could be some caching issue. Are there any other rules in the htaccess for oldomain? Is olddomain using the same folder as example.com? Can you check the headers sent?

Comment: Oops! It's working. Probably a cache issue then. Thanks a lot Gerben. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTPS rewritecond is incorrect. Cond is a regex, not an quality test. It should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
```

The `%{HTTPS}` var will only ever contain `on` or `off`. Never `=on`, so the match fails and triggers the redirect, even if https really is on.

---

update

For an unconditional HTTP->HTTPS redirect you'd need to redirect to an https URL. Your version just detects if HTTPS is **OFF*, then redirects to the same url, causing a loop. What you need is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Marc, that did not work either. Can you edit your answer with the full rule? (Probably I am missing something.)

Comment: Okay, maybe I wasn't clear. I wanted people who came from `HTTP://olddomain.com/1.html` to be redirected to `HTTP://newdomain.com/1.html` and those who came from `HTTPS://olddomain.com/1.html` to be redirected to `HTTPS://newdomain.com/1.html`, and so forth. That is, if they came from HTTP connection, they'll be redirected to HTTP new domain. If they came from HTTPS connection, they'll be redirected to HTTPS new domain. I want htaccess rules for that. Can you help?