# Applying IP rules to HTTP only (and not HTTPS) with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been setting up an IP blocklist reciently and I was wondering is it possible to block an IP that is connecting via HTTP and not to block them if they connect via HTTPS. There was a post on SO [.Htaccess rules to redirect respective HTTP links to HTTP and HTTPS to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705153/htaccess-rules-to-redirect-respective-http-links-to-http-and-https-to-https) which is similar but uses `mod_rewrite` which I have had horrible experience with and has only given me 500 errors in the past . Is there any way to do it with the standard format?

```
order allow,deny 
allow from 192.168.1.0/24
deny from all
```

I need support for IPv6 addresses too. If the rewrite method is the only option, in your answer could you include a link that I could look at to perform my task properly? Many thanks!

I am using Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you desire isn't built into Apache's [`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html) mechanism. Simply: no protocol level commands are supported by `mod_auth` or `mod_access`. Furthermore, what you seek breaks the expected assumption that if you provide a resource over HTTP, that same path will work over HTTPS. This will cause surprising results for people using [HTTPS enforcers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beaholcfmnpbabojbldnhlikfmnjmoma).

But, if you're dead set on doing something like this, I would recommend [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). You can use it to do all kinds of nifty things, like denying access to the cache from certain protocols on a per-file basis, and otherwise fiddling with data coming off your Apache server before you serve it to your users.

Comment: I have used Squid for a firewall transparent proxy and have little experience. Does Squid work nicely with Apache on a Ubuntu server? I use a self-signed SSL certificate too.

Comment: @user99545 It should. I haven't played with it in some time, though, so I recommend [the docs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/) or http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: Cool. +1 for the point you made about HTTPS enforcers that I would have completely overlooked.